# how do i alias some constant string in git

Tags: git, alias

I know I can alias commands in git, but my branch name has some constant prefix, so can I alias this prefix?

Like this:

Branch name: `bugfix_0000_00000000`

I want to alias the `bugfix_0000` into `bug` so I can check out this branch by `git checkout bug_00000000`.

Here is what I tried:

- Alias `bugfix_0000` into `bug`, but not work for me.
- I also had alias `git checkout` to `gck`, but`gck bug_00000000` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using git bash for windows, in the bash shell run

```
echo export bug="bugfix_0000" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

and then

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

or reopen the shell.

Now you can use `${bug}` in commands where `bugfix_0000` is needed.

```
git checkout ${bug}_000000
```

If you are using Ubuntu, you could add the export in `~/.bashrc`. For other systems, there is a similar file.

Comment: if i need more constant string, just need to add the code like this: "export bug=bugfix_0000" ?
My .bash_profile file are like this:
# generated by Git for Windows
test -f ~/.profile && . ~/.profile
test -f ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc
export bug=bugfix_0000
export mstr=master_0000
Only bug are available, mstr is not available.

Comment: After appending `export mstr=master_0000` to `~/.bash_profile`, you could use `${mstr}` in commands where `master_0000` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, aliases can only be defined for commands, not for parameters.

What you could do (assuming *nix) is to create a simple one-line script called e.g. `git-cobug` (CheckOut BUG) and store it somewhere reachable from your `$PATH`:

```
#!/bin/bash
git checkout bugfix_0000_$1
```

Then you could use it like: `git cobug 00000000` in order to checkout `bugfix_0000_00000000` branch.

---

Another suitable thing you could do (assuming Bash shell) which might remove the need for such an alias is to setup your git for tab-completion, as described in [Git Manual - Tips and Tricks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Basics-Tips-and-Tricks):

Download the file https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
and source it from your .bashrc file.

This way, you can type `git checkout bu` and then press tab, and the shell will auto-complete it
 to `bugfix_0000_0000000` (so you only have to type the remaining 1, 2 or 3) if the only branches you have which start with `bu` are `bugfix_0000_00000001`, `bugfix_0000_00000002`, and `bugfix_0000_00000003`.